# Animate each item of Listview when displaying

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-animation

I am trying to show listview elments in a manner that each one of them animates and then become visible so after one by one they animate and get visible to user.
but When I implemented the animation, its not working on individial item, but working on the whole listview :(

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_row, parent, false);




        tvCatName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvCatName);

        tvCatName.setText(Data.alCategoriesModels.get(position).catname);


        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toasts.pop(activity, "Category id :  " + Data.alCategoriesModels.get(position).catID); 

            }
        });

//      row.setAnimation(animation);
        row.startAnimation(animation);

        return row;
    }
```

[image]

How to make one by one animation on each element of list view. I am extend ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 14):

You can apply a `android:layoutAnimation` on the `ListView`.

- Create your animation XML file in `anim` folder. For example (`slide_right_in.xml`):

  ```
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fillAfter="true"
      android:duration="400"
      android:fromXDelta="-100%"
      android:toXDelta="0%"/>
  ```
- Create another animation XML file with root element `layoutAnimation` :(`my_layout_animation.xml`)

  ```
  <layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:animation="@anim/slide_right_in"
      android:delay="0.5"/>
  ```
- Apply it on any `ViewGroup` you want. For example `ListView`:

  ```
  <ListView
      android:layoutAnimation = "@anim/my_layout_animation"
      ... />
  ```

Comment: this causes the app to crash

Comment: @Postback Let me know type of crash which you got (stacktrace)

Comment: Just tried this code and then then i've taken it out again. So can't provide you details. As soon as i opened the Activity with the listView, the app crashed

Comment: @Postback I've used this code in my apps many times and works fine. You can refer to docs about layout animation or post your stack trace

Comment: so simple it's brilliant

Comment: thanks for this. But, this only work for the newly created item, not the others. any workout?

Comment: how do you restart the animation when the list is repopulated?

Comment: make sure to set `my_layout_animation` to `RecyclerView`, at first I settle `slide_right_in` and that has caused the app crash. Outstanding animation for a `RecyclerView` btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
int delay=(position-list.getFirstVisiblePosition)*200;
if(delay<=200)
    delay=200;
animation.setStartOffset(delay);
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

After messing with my own Animation implementation which kind of worked half of the times, I've found the [ListViewAnimations#ExpandableListItemAdapter](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/wiki/ExpandableListItemAdapter) which was exactly what I needed.

Here is their API demo app on Google Play: [ListViewAnimations](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.listviewanimations)

Answer (score 0):

here is a tutorial to  **[Android ListView animation](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-listview-animation-2.html)** 

**EDIT :**
the idea is creating a listener and animate view inside it:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,final View view, final int position,
      long id) {
           anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

               @Override
              public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
              }

              @Override
              public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

              @Override 
              public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    ItemDetail item = aAdpt.getItem(position);
                    aAdpt.remove(item);
              }
          });
      view.startAnimation(anim);
  }
});
```